# How to flash Mts Blaze 5?

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, custom-roms, flashtool, zte-blade

I would like to flash my Android Phone because it appears to be corrupted;  whenever I switch on my phone it gets stuck on the MTS logo (splash) screen.

I have recently downloaded a 'flash tool,' but it is not detecting my phone.

Please Help.

Comment: Personally I'd send it back if it's new. Can you see it when you plug it into the computer. Ensure you remove Sim/SD card if you've put those in before you reboot it and also plug it in when you do.

Comment: its searching for some drivers and after that driver not found.

Comment: Have you taken the sim and the SD card out?

Comment: yes i taken our both sim+ sd_card

Comment: I'd send it back then, assuming you've not modified it since you had it? What did ZTE say, if anything?

Comment: ZTE says the there is not software available for this phone

Comment: Try http://www.mtsindia.in/blaze5.0/ (I meant MTS not ZTE) drivers there. Did you modify the phone?

Comment: but i don't know the procedure of how to re-install new android Operating System in Mobile Phone.